# use MySQL server as "cache"

Tags: php, mysql, caching, ram

I know this is a weird question but I have 2 servers, one a vps and another, a mysql host. Now my issue is that I want to try and lower the load on the vps as it is a startup 128mb vps.

Slight problem, what would be required to make the MySQL server work as if it were a cache, I have no access to anything on the MySQL server save the databases im given.

Will this require a separate database? please tell me so if it is possible i can ask my host to add another database.

Thanks!

Comment: @wyzard Of the page data being read. so this would perhaps include raw php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you host a website on the VPS that uses MySQL as the database, a typical request goes like this:

- the client makes a request to the web server running on your VPS
- your script running inside the web server makes a database query
- the database returns the query results
- your script formats and prints the results
- the results appear in the browser (client)

There is no way to make a request hit the database without going through the web server first.

If you want to lighten the load on the VPS you can make your script run faster. The most time-consuming part of most web applications is making database queries and waiting for the results. You can, in a lot of cases, avoid that by caching the results of your database queries *on the VPS* using an in-memory cache like [memcached](http://memcached.org). Be careful with the memory settings though - be sure to set the maximum allocated memory to a sufficiently low setting because your server has very little memory.

Here is a basic example of caching the result of a SELECT query:

```
$cache = new Memcached();
$cache->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$article_key = "article[$article_id]";
$article = $cache->get($article_key);

if ($article === FALSE) {
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = :id");
    $statement->exec(array('id' => $article_id));
    $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (count($result) === 0) {
        // return a 404 status
    }
    $article = $result[0]; 
    $cache->set($article_key, $article);
}

// display the article
```

Comment: is there any minimum for memcached memory? i can only afford 10-20mb tops

Comment: and is memcached the best option?

Comment: I don't think there is a minimum. Memcached is a pretty good and time-tested cache, it is a very reliable solution. Please tell me what kind of web application you are hosting. What database operations are the most frequent (is it read or write-heavy)? How many images and other static assets are you serving? That way I can give you more specific advice.

Comment: every page refresh there is an insert, an update and on some pages it is several loops of information being fetched, if you want to see it in action, some of the heavy pages would be content (e.g.: http://www.pamzam.com/507ee090d02bc) and user profiles (e.g.: http://www.pamzam.com/user/muqman) i hope this helps give an idea as to what i need

Comment: The site loads pretty fast for me. Have you experienced any performance problems? Maybe there isn't even a need to optimize it. What kind of load do you expect (how many requests/second on average)? You can test the site using a web benchmark tool like "ab" (Apache Benchmark). See how many req/s you can make and monitor the memory usage while making the requests. If you don't see anything anomalous, I don't think you should worry about performance.

Comment: Its not really about average activity but my issue is if some of my friends decide to play around with me and start to refresh the page at 150 reqs/sec then the server crashes, plus i do have a script to limit it but still the execution is added to the ram used. if it doesnt need cache then, im new to servers and know next to nothing about hardware. thanks!

Comment: OK. Most of the content on the site seems to be pretty static, so I think caching the result of SELECT queries can lead to a significant performance improvement. I will edit my answer to include a code sample on how to do it.

Comment: 1k reqs with apachebench messes up the server

Comment: I posted an example. You need to install memcached and the memcached PHP extension first. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php

Comment: this will do it, im sure, i've marked it as answer but may i ask, when turning on memcached how will i set the memory to 15mb?

Comment: Thank you. Here is a detailed answer about how to configure memcached: http://serverfault.com/a/347622/103721. You only need to change the value of the `-m` option in your config (the other values are better left the way they are until you specifically need them).

Comment: wait and would i add everything about the article to the cache?

Comment: and where would i add the article to the cache

ps: does http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/how-to-install-memcached-in-ubuntu/ work?

Comment: Yes, it should work. If you are not familiar with vi though, you'll be better off using another editor (like nano) to edit the config file.

Comment: thanks! im implementing it right now, and um is 10mb sufficient? i dont want to set it to anything much higher but i can do 20 if needed

Comment: It all depends on how much data you have in your DB. Try it with 10 MB and see how fast it gets.

Comment: ok, ill do that but the only thing is, im getting "Failed to fetch http://mirrors.buyvm.net/ubuntu/pool/main/m/memcached/memcached_1.4.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" i tried apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade is disabled

Comment: If apt-get doesn't work you can try to download the package manually. I've just made a Google search for "memcached_1.4.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb" and found this page: http://packages.trisquel.info/dagda/i386/memcached/download. Download this file: http://us.archive.trisquel.info/trisquel/pool/main/m/memcached/memcached_1.4.5-1ubuntu2_i386.deb using the command wget (type `man wget` to get help). Then try installing it: http://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get. If that fails, try asking a question on superuser.com - I'm not a Linux wizard unfortunately :(

Comment: hmm memcached overloaded my ram even at 10mb, it used about 40mb more baseline ram... any ideas?

Comment: Maybe. And it can also do opcode caching. You can try Redis too.

Comment: interesting, ill get back to you tomorrow, its late here. thanks for your time!

Comment: Hmm... sort of an off topic question to this thread but do you by any chance know how to disable the logging on specific IP addresses in Apache?